# Sklearn train_test_split() equivalent in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

This is the Sklearn version function to split data

```
sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(*arrays, test_size=None, train_size=None, random_state=None, shuffle=True, stratify=None)
```

I need the Sklearn train_test_split() equivalent in PySpark which can be given arguments to stratify on the target, has option whether to shuffle the data or not and things like that.
The train_test_split() is a fantastic handy function and it would be best to have its closest possible implementation.
randomSplit() function doesn't match.

Comment: Good question. I also need this. We can provide the input to the ```train_test_split``` developer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the stratification problem in Pyspark data splitting function.

Stratified sampling in pyspark can be achieved by using sampleBy, lets say the column on which you want to stratify the sample is "colname" sampled = df.sampleBy("colname", fractions={4: 0.2, 6: 0.4, 8: 0.2}, seed=0)

Also did a little search and found out that it is without replacement.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sampleBy.html

Comment: Thank you. How can we decide the ```fractions``` argument?

Comment: One can decide based on the representation in a similar data like the bigger population or even as per one's own use case where let's say someone wants the fractions to be equal for gender. Many factors can be considered,